# How to make invoking ruby without arguments open a REPL?

Tags: command-line, bash, python, ruby

I'm used to executing `python` in the Terminal to get to an interactive Python session where I can try things before using them in a script. In Ruby, however, executing `ruby` doesn't work like that (the REPL is called `irb`).

How can I make it so that calling `ruby` without arguments executes `irb` and `ruby ex1.rb`, `ruby --help`, etc. still work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this surprisingly simple Python script (hah):

```py
import sys, os

if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    os.system('irb')
else:
    os.system('ruby ' + sys.argv[1])
```

I saved this as `ruby.py` in my home directory and added it to my `.zshrc` as follows:

```
alias ruby="python ~/ruby.py"
```

and it's working.

I'm wondering if this is the best or a bug-free solution, though. (For instance with other scripts)